# Using enum string type as dictionary key in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, enums

I have a enum

```
enum FilterType:String {
    case UnitSoldFilter = "UnitSoldFilter"
    case AmountFilter = "AmountFilter"
}
```

I want a method in which I want to save corresponding value

```
    func getFilterForType(filterFor:FilterForType) -> NSData? {

        if let data: NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(filterKey) as? NSData{
return data
            }
            return nil
    }
```

But I am getting **error** as we can't use `filterKey` directly. How this can be solved.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but shouldn't you be able to simply filter by filterFor.rawValue, which would return the string you are assigning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. In Swift 2.0 you don't need to specify the `String` that the `Enum` corresponds to *if* they're the same string.

So

```
enum FilterType:String {
    case UnitSoldFilter = "UnitSoldFilter"
    case AmountFilter = "AmountFilter"
}
```

Becomes

```
enum FilterType:String {
    case UnitSoldFilter
    case AmountFilter
}
```

And then inside of your method you're going to use the `rawValue` property.

```
func getFilterForType(filterFor:FilterForType) -> NSData? {

        if let data: NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(filterKey.rawValue) as? NSData{
return data
            }
            return nil
    }
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `filterKey` is of the `FilterType` type, not `String`. Call the `rawValue` property to get the string:

```
func getFilterForType(filterKey:FilterForType) -> NSData? {
    if let data: NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(filterKey) as? NSData {
        return data
    }
    return nil
}
```